# What is the translation of the label on this piece of agricultural equipment?

Tags: vocabulary, translation

[image]

A word by word translation is okay too.
Also... if you could write the original text in korean it would be awesome.
I am really bad when it comes to Asian languages... i've struggled a lot to learn english and french and that's when i stopped learning other languages...

Comment: welcome to a site where learners of the korean language continue learning korean, and other languages.  if one of the vocabulary words that you searched for is vexing you, posting this picture along with the one word and which definitions of it you feel may be representative of it would make for a great post.

Comment: I don't really know any korean word... for now, at least. I am trying to find this specifical item on ebay but i can t find it. I know what it does. I managed to deduct that it s a "모종이식기"... but i can t find it on ebay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(한손) = One hand
모종 = seedling
이식기 = a transplanter

So it's a '(one handed) seedling transplanter'.

카이로스 is the company name. If you search for **카이로스 모종이식기** you can find it on sale in Korea.